# Алгоритм нахождения расстояния между несколькими точками

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты! Прошу вашей помощи. Необходимо найти расстояния пройденные от передатчика до приемника, отраженные от цели. Заданы координаты 2-х передатчиков `Rtransfer[3][2]`, 2-х целей `Rtarget[3][2]` и 16-ти приемников `Rresiver[3][16]`.
Код:

```
    float **Dist;
    int rows;
    rows=50;
    int col;
    col=2;

    Dist = new float*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
         Dist[i] = new float[rows];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
         {
              for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
              {
                   for (int N = 0; N < m; N++)
                   {
                        Dist[i][j]=sqrt(pow((Rtarget[0][j]-Rtransfer[0][n]),2)+pow((Rtarget[1][j]-Rtransfer[1][n]),2)+pow((Rtarget[2][j]-Rtransfer[2][n]),2))+sqrt(pow((Rtarget[0][j]-Rresiv[0][N]),2)+pow((Rtarget[1][j]-Rresiv[1][N]),2)+pow((Rtarget[2][j]-Rresiv[2][N]),2));

                        StringGrid2->Cells[i][j]=FloatToStrF(Dist[i][j],ffGeneral,7,2);
                   }
              }
         }
    }
```

При этом получается массив из одинаковых чисел. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В чем ошибка ? Что именно не нравится ?

Comment: Чему равна переменная m?

Comment: 16 это количество приемников

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, формулу расчета в адекватном виде, судя по всему - в ней ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное здесь имелось в виду **`cols`**

```
Dist[i] = new float[rows];
```

Comment: Одно число получается, а должен быть наьор всевозможных расстояний. По-моему, это не суть, как заполнится массив в строку или в столбец

Answer (score 0):

```
Dist[i][j]=sqrt(pow((Rtarget[0][j]-Rtransfer[0][n]),2)
+pow((Rtarget[1][j]-Rtransfer[1][n]),2)
+pow((Rtarget[2][j]-Rtransfer[2][n]),2))//посчитали расстояния от  передатчиков до целей
+sqrt(pow((Rtarget[0][j]-Rresiv[0][N]),2)//расстояния от целей до приемников
+pow((Rtarget[1][j]-Rresiv[1][N]),2)
+pow((Rtarget[2][j]-Rresiv[2][N]),2));
```